"Your user name and password are not defined." when trying to create a Firebird database using FbConnection.CreateDatabase()
I have inherited a project for which the original developer is no longer available. When debugging the solution in Visual Studio 2022, I'm getting a runtime exception that seems to be caused by calling FbConnection.CreateDatabase(). The full exception is:

Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database
administrator to set up a Firebird login.

The error indicates that the user name and password are not defined, but I've been unable to determine where the user name and password need to be added.
I've spent some time investigating the issue but I'm new to Firebird and the project so I haven't had much success. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I've attached the relevant snippet of code with details below. The "databaseDirectory" is defined as Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, which, on Windows 11, evaluates to "C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\". The "databaseFile" is "database.fdb4".
if (!Directory.Exists(databaseDirectory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(databaseDirectory);
}

var preparedDatabasePath = Path.Combine(databaseDirectory, databaseFile);

var connectionString = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    ConnectionLifeTime = 0,
    Dialect = 3,
    Database = preparedDatabasePath,
    ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
    ClientLibrary = "fbclient",
    UserID = "SYSDBA",
    Password = "masterkey",
    Pooling = true,
    MinPoolSize = 0,
    MaxPoolSize = 80,
    Charset = "none"
};

if (!File.Exists(connectionString.Database))
{
    FbConnection.CreateDatabase(connectionString.ToString());
}

When installing Firebird 5.0 for Windows x64, I kept the default options, including the SYSADMIN user and default password of "masterkey". The Firebird server is running locally as a service (image below). It is installed in the directory "C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_5_0". That is also where the "fbclient.dll" is located.
Firebird Server running as a Service
I'm running Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11. My account has admin privileges. I've tried running Visual Studio 2022 "as admin" but still get the error. The project has version 8.5.4 of the FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird NuGet package installed.
I don't know if this is a permissions issue, an issue with the credentials being supplied, an issue with trying to connect to an embedded server, or something else. Any help would be appreciated.

The error probably indicates that you are loading an fbclient.dll which does not have access to the database engine, and as such is not actually Firebird Embedded and thus tries to connect through the server., Find out which fbclient.dll actually gets loaded (e.g. with Process Monitor).

Thank you @MarkRotteveel! I found that hard-coding the path to the dll I wanted worked (not a long-term solution, but it gets me where I need to be for now). It looks like the fbclient.dll that was being referenced did not have the correct information in it.
